# Is it possible to trim some middle part of a video or screen recording on the iPhone or iPad to upload to YouTube?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, video-editing, screen-recording

I know how to trim start and trim end of a video or screen recording on the iPhone or iPad and upload to YouTube.  But what if there are a few seconds in the video showing my user ID and I hope to blur it out or cut that few seconds out, is that possible inside of iPhone or iPad?

One way is, I can trim the original into two videos. So for example, if the original video is 00:00 to 03:00, and I want to remove  02:00 to 02:06, then I can trim start / end to make video 1 as 00:00 to 2:00 and video 2 as 2:06 to 03:00 and then I have removed 02:00 to 02:06, but now I have two separate videos. Can I still somehow join them or upload to YouTube as 1 video?

Comment: Are you looking for apps on iPad which can do it (iMovie _should_ be able to do it), or whether youtube can do it or not? Their web-app-studio might be able to do it, if it runs on mobile Safari/ chrome.

Comment: As @Ankii already indicated, there is no built-in function to achieve this. This is a very simple task though, so basically any video editing software, even for mobile should be able to do this.

Comment: I wonder if iMovie can do something like that

Comment: @nopole try it out! :) it’s free

Comment: of course iMovie can, trimming and cutting is **very** basic. Any video editing software that can't achieve this, is not a video editing software.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the Apple ecosystem and I had a similar question, but for my MacBook. I'm not sure this applies to iPhone/iPad, but I found [Trimming Clips or Cutting Parts Out of the Middle Using Quicktime](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82CiWXI4rlQ) on YouTube explaining how to remove a middle part of a movie. You might not need to join the pieces:

- Open your movie with the QuickTime Player
- Go to the beginning of the region/time frame you want to remove (in your case 2:00), go to **Edit** > **Split Clip**, and when the chunks from the splitting are displayed, click **Done**
- Go to the end of the region/time frame you want to remove (in your case 2:06), and again click **Edit** > **Split Clip**, now, since you see the splittings you could delete the one in the middle, with the Delete key (from the keyboard). I'm not sure how you do the deletion on iPad/iPhone since I don't have any of these.
- Save the movie

Note: On my MacBook Pro the splittings are barely visible, but you can see in the preview region that there are some distinct chunks. Also, for me, it was difficult to see what a chunk contained, so I hit the play button and I had to look very carefully for the vertical red line. You can pause the movie and move that vertical red line (the cursor) inside the chunk you want to delete to ensure you're deleting what you want.